# How to prevent Elmah logging errors handled in a Error Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I am using Elmah and Elmah.mvc packages in a asp.net, mvc4 web app.  I have a specific controller action where I want to handle `HttpAntiForgeryExceptions` in a specific manner.  I have created a custom HandleErrorAttribute that inherits from `HandleErrorAttribute` and implements `IExceptionFilter`.

Under the specific circumstances I want to handle, I set the `ExceptionContext.ExceptionHandled` to true.  The behaviour that the user sees is correct and the error is handled as I want it to be.  However, it also logs an error to Elmah, which I don't want it to do, as I would like to keep the Elmah log for true errors.

The controller annotation looks like:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CustomHandleAntiforgeryError]
public ActionResult ControllerMethod(Model model) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

The CustomHandleAntiforgeryError looks like:

```
public class CustomHandleAntiforgeryErrorAttribute: 
                              HandleErrorAttribute, IExceptionFilter 
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (circumstancesAreOk) 
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do to prevent this error being logged with Elmah?

--- EDIT ---

Looking at the Elmah.MVC source the [HandleErrorAttribute](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc/blob/master/src/Elmah.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs) logs both handled and unhandled errors

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnException(context);

        if (!context.ExceptionHandled) // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
            return;

        var e = context.Exception;
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;
        if (httpContext != null && 
            (RaiseErrorSignal(e, httpContext) // prefer signaling, if possible
             || IsFiltered(e, httpContext))) // filtered?
            return;

        LogException(e, httpContext);
    }
```

I would like a way within my custom attribute to signal to Elmah not to log this error and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: any luck with this one. by the looks of your EDIT above, Elmah returns out of the method if Exception is handled?

Comment: Described what I did, which works for me but is not a great solution to deal with a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

See ErrorFiltering from [Elmah's documentation](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering). Here's the introduction:

> When an unhandled exception is reported to ELMAH by ASP.NET, an
>   application can decide whether to dismiss the exception or not. There
>   are two ways for an application to do this, either programmatically or
>   declaratively via the configuration file. The simpler of the two is
>   programmatically because you do not need to learn anything new except
>   write an event handler in your favorite language. The downside of the
>   programmatic approach is that you need to write code and modify your
>   web application (requiring possibly a static re-compile). With the
>   configuration-based approach, you can simply apply filtering of
>   exceptions to a running application.

Comment: But this is about dealing with unhandled exceptions. However, even when I set the exceptionhandled to true elmah still logs the error.

Comment: I have exactly same problem.. I searched complete app from all sides, I cannot find the point where elmah is logging handled exceptions

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this I think is ugly, but worked for the weird error filter corner case that I was experiencing.  I added a custom HandleErrorAttribute, copied from the Elmah [HandleErrorAttribute](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc/blob/master/src/Elmah.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs) and included a null check in the OnException method.

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnException(context);

        if (!context.ExceptionHandled) // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
            return;

        string[] formKeys = context.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys;

        var e = context.Exception;

        // linked to CustomErrorAttribute
        if (e == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool test = HostingEnvironment.IsHosted;

        var httpContext = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;
        if (httpContext != null &&
            (RaiseErrorSignal(e, httpContext) // prefer signaling, if possible
             || IsFiltered(e, httpContext))) // filtered?
            return;

        LogException(e, httpContext);
    }
```

Then, in my error filter, which I did not want to trigger messaging to Elmah, as well as setting the ExceptionContext ExceptionHandled to true I set the Exception to null

```
public class MyCustomErrorFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
         if (blah, blah, blah, weird things but not something terrible) 
         {
            filterContext.Exception = null;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            return;
         }
     }
 }
```

If it was something more involved and a regular occurrence I would probably fork Elmah and look at creating a custom Elmah build as this feels a little bit hacky to rely on in multiple situations.